# Ruby on Rails - conditionally checking check_box_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, model-view-controller

I'm trying to conditionally mark a check_box_tag as checked depending on the instance variable @ratings_filter that comes from the server. I can't use Javascript so what I do on the controller is to instantiate @ratings_filter setting it equal to  session[:ratings]. Then in the view I'm telling check_box_tag function to set the box as marked either if @ratings_filter is nil (by default, it should display all) or if its value on the hash is true (which means it was marked by the user, ergo it should be displayed)

```
= form_tag movies_path, :id => :ratings_form, :method => :get do
  Include:
  - @all_ratings.each do |rating|
    = rating
    = check_box_tag "ratings[#{rating}]", (@ratings_filter.nil? or @ratings_filter[rating] == true ? true : false) , :id => "ratings_#{rating}"
  = submit_tag 'Refresh', :id => 'ratings_submit'
```

This approach isn't working and I can't finde the problem.
Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: `:id => :ratings_#{rating}` this will give you just `:ratings_` symbol

Comment: Replaced but same problem: 

= check_box_tag "ratings[#{rating}]", (@ratings_filter.nil? or @ratings_filter[rating] == true ? true : false) , :id => "ratings_#{rating}"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please note that the code: `:id => :ratings_#{rating}` will give you just `:ratings_` symbol, i.e. in [html](/questions/tagged/html) code you'll have: `id="ratings_"`, please fix the code to `:id => :"ratings_#{rating}"`

Next, according the [documentation](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/check_box_tag), `#check_box_tag` helper's method accepts the checked property state via 3rd argument, not the 2nd, and 2nd (mandatory) argument is the value, which will be passed to server with request. So the code will be:

```
check_box_tag "ratings[#{rating}]", "1", @ratings_filter.try(:fetch, rating) != false , :id => :"ratings_#{rating}"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I thought that that second argument was optional

Comment: @StringerBell the second argument will be passed to server via request

Comment: @StringerBell and all the unequated argument (which is beginning from  begin) are mandatory